# Capturing changed values from a Repeater on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, postback, repeater

This is plaguing me and I've read countless solutions that all seem to be off a bit.  I have a repeater that has 2 drop downs per item and a few items.  These all have potential values 0-8 that the user can select and I want to gather the data on a postback when the user click a button on the bottom of the page.

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPricing" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPricing_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Row clear">
            <div class="Column Cat"><%# ((Price)Container.DataItem).AgeCategory %></div>
            <div id="dWasPrice" runat="server" class="Column Was">
                <asp:Literal ID="litPreviousPrice" runat="server" /><span class="strike"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="Column Now">$<%# ((Price)Container.DataItem).FullPrice %></div>
            <div class="Column Deposit">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountForPart" runat="server" skucode="<%# ((Price)Container.DataItem).PartHeaderCode %>">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>                        
            </div>
            <div class="Column Full">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountForFull" runat="server" skucode="<%# ((Price)Container.DataItem).FullHeaderCode %>">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the binding.

```
private void BindDetails()
{
    SetDiscountContent();

    rptPricing.DataSource = _Detail.Prices;
    rptPricing.DataBind();
}
```

Here is where the data is not present.

```
if ( IsPostBack && UIControlUtil.GetPostBackControl(Page) == lnkAddToCart)
{
    //populate the cart without javascript
    //find the drop down with items selected and create Order Elements
    try
    {
        var orders = new Order[0];
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptPricing.Items)
        {
            var dl = item.FindControl("ddlCountForFull");
            if (dl != null)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref orders, orders.Length + 1);
                orders[orders.Length - 1] = new Order() {
                    Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dl.SelectedValue),
                    Sku = dl.Attributes["skucode"]};
```

I've tried moving the call to `BindDetails()` around from `PageLoad` to `OnInit` and also playing with the postback flag.  I have also played with the `ViewState` flags to no avail.

EDIT (Adding Page Load), please note I have played with moving this to the OnInit.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ContentItem == null) return;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var control = (ContentManagement.Library.Sitecore.PreDefinedControl)ContentItem;
            _Detail = (Details)control.DataElements[0];
            BindDetails();
        }

        if (ShoppingCartHelper.GetProductsOfTInCart<blah>() > 8)
        {
            lnkAddToCart.Enabled = false;
            lnkAddToCart.CssClass = lnkAddToCart.CssClass + " disabled cartmax";
        }
    }
```

Comment: "the data is not present" - do you mean that `item.FindControl("ddlCountForFull")` is null, or that `dl.SelectedValue` is empty?

Comment: Also, `var orders = new Order[0];`, and then `orders[orders.Length - 1] = new Order()` will cause an error at runtime.

Comment: there are no items so calling FindControl is pointless, if I rebind on a postback then there are values, but the selected value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

First off make sure you are doing a:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BindDetails();
}
```

This will ensure you are not binding with every postback and losing your data.

Also, I do not understand the need for:

```
if ( IsPostBack && UIControlUtil.GetPostBackControl(Page) == lnkAddToCart)
```

Why do you not just implement the `OnClick` handler for a `Button` or `LinkButton` and move all of your code to pull the data out of the repeated into the handler?

Also make sure `ViewState` is enabled or you will not be able to iterate through the `Repeater` to find the changed values.

**EDIT:**

Check that you have not disabled `ViewState` in on of the containers that the `Repeater` exists in.  You should have the data.  The only reason you wouldn't is if `ViewState` is disabled on the control or one of it's parents or you are wiping the values in some way such as rebinding.  Can you post more of your code like your `Page_Load` and any event that will occur after it?

Try putting a `TextBox` after the `Repeater` and enter soem text in it and then post your `Repeater`. Can you see the text in the `TextBox` that you entered?  If not then a parent control has disabled `ViewState` or at the page level.  If you can see the value, then somewhere you are rebinding to `Repeater` unintentionally and wiping your data out.  You need to put a breakpoint where you do the binding and ensure that it is NOT occurring when you post back.

There isn't much more help I can give you at this point.

Comment: I made changes based on your suggestions and it makes no difference whether I use a an OnClick event handler or the other method.  the result is the same, rptPricing has no Items nor Controls unless I rebind.  ViewState is Enabled, and it appear as if it is tracking it

Comment: yeah, the only container is a panel that has viewstate turned on the values for EnableViewState on the DropDown, Repeater, Panel are all set to true, the value of IsTrackingViewState is true. I added my page load, and some comments.  The textbox date is present.

Comment: I revisited this morning and it appears if I take off the custom attributes everything works fine.  My front end guy prefers using these attributes but I suppose a different solution is in order, would this function differently in 4.0?

Comment: and I added them back and it still works.  weird.  Perhaps just a fresh eye this morning

Comment: @Rob A fresh eyes always helps :) Also in your `Page_Load` you have: ` lnkAddToCart.CssClass = lnkAddToCart.CssClass + " disabled cartmax"` which seems odd because after a few post backs your links class is going to have a ton of repeated `disable cartmax` definitions. Your link will persist the `CssClass` property via the `ViewState` so each post back where your `if` gets triggered it will be appending data possibly multiple times. Furthermore, I RARELY use `OnInit`. Remember `ViewState` is load AFTER `OnInit` but before `Page_Load` so that might have been your problem.

Comment: thanks Kelsey, I had moved my binding from page_load to OnInit in an effort to resolve the issue.  It is always hard to post code that I have to obfuscate, and that I have butchered while trying to fix the issue.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @Rob A did this end up fixing your problem or help at all?